# Python - Changing one JSON array changes every array

Tags: python

I have this code, I am trying to append arrays then change their status into randomize status

```
list_account_status = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
array_body = copy.deepcopy(response_body)

for _ in range (1,count):
    array_body["Data"]["Account"].append(array_body["Data"]["Account"][0])

for account_row in range (0,count):
    rand = random.choice(list_account_status)
    array_body["Data"]["Account"][account_row].update({
        "Status": rand
    })

print(json.dumps(array_body))
```

This will produce this kind of output

```
    {
    "Data": {
        "Account": [
            {
                "Status": "3"
            },
            {
                "Status": "3"
            },
            {
                "Status": "3"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Links": "",
    "Meta": ""
}
```

I am expecting to have a randomize Status per json array like this

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Account": [
            {
                "Status": "3"
            },
            {
                "Status": "1"
            },
            {
                "Status": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Links": "",
    "Meta": ""
}
```

How can I end up to that?

Comment: can you edit your question to add an expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This happens because all the elements in the `account` array is the reference to the original dictionary.
2. so updating any one of the reference will reflect in all the elements as they are pointing to the same object

Use deep copy to make duplicates

```
for _ in range (1, 3):
    array_body["Data"]["Account"].append(copy.deepcopy(array_body["Data"]["Account"][0]))
```

**OR**

You could use `=` to assign value to index of a list which will replace the reference with new object references

```
    array_body["Data"]["Account"][account_row]={
        "Status": rand
    }
```

Comment: @gummybear hey I just figured out the actual reason, just updated the answer. cheers!

Comment: Yup, saw it. Thanks for the explanation. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the selected value from **list_account_status**

```
 for account_row in range (0,count):
    rand = random.choice(list_account_status)
    list_account_status.remove(rand)
    array_body["Data"]["Account"][account_row].update({
        "Status": rand})
```

Comment: I tried it, but the output is still the same on actual.